# How to create switching button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create a switching button with movable action like if it's showing on dark side it's should dark and if it's show light side. Can any body help with how this could be written
.

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".styleswitch").click(function() {
    $('link[rel=stylesheet]').attr('href' , $(this).attr('rel')); 
  });
});
  </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dark.css" />
<title>Switch Theme</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="styleswitch" rel="css/dark.css">Dark</a>
<a href="#" class=" styleswitch " rel="css/light.css">Light</a>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
<div id="module-a"><a href="#" class="styleswitch" rel="css/dark.css">Dark</a>
<a href="#" class=" styleswitch " rel="css/light.css">Light</a></div>
<div id="module-b">Module1</div>
<div id="module-c">Module1</div>
<div id="module-d">Module1</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? show some code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this: - I fond this in some place..

```
$j("#button1").live('click',function(){  
    //Fade out form if shown and fade in form selected
    $jtest2.fadeOut("slow", function(){
         $jtest1.fadeIn("slow");  
    });

    //The following is inside the click so I do not get added until the first click 
    //and added after every click so I multiply! 
    //Hence why it takes 2 clicks

    $j('#button1').live('click', function(){
        //change class from light to dark
        $j(this).addClass('dark_button').removeClass('light_button');
    }); //I need to change this class to light if
        // button 2 is selected and change button 2 to dark
});
```

you can also try this :--

```
$j("#button1, #button2").live('click',
    function(){  

        //figure out what button was clicked. 
        if(this.id === "button1"){
            var btnA = $j(this);
            var btnB = $j("#button2");
            var divA = $j('#test1');
            var divB = $j('#test2');
        }
        else{
            btnA = $j(this);
            btnB = $j("#button1");
            divA = $j('#test2');
            divB = $j('#test1');
        }

        //make sure it is not already active, no use to show/hide when it is already set
        if(btnA.hasClass('dark_button')){
            return; 
        }

        //see if div is visible, if so hide, than show first div
        if(divB.is(":visible")){        
            divB.fadeOut("slow", function(){
                 divA.fadeIn("slow");
            });
        }
        else{//if already hidden, just show the first div
            divA.fadeIn("slow");            
        }

        //Add and remove classes to the buttons to switch state
        btnA.addClass('dark_button').removeClass('light_button');
        btnB.removeClass('dark_button').addClass('light_button');
    }    
);
```

Comment: you can use your html code .. u just have to declare class or id and have to use css..

Comment: i just working with first code but i am not able to see the out put i am using this way in html <div id="button1" class="light_button"></div>

Comment: you can do this by using buttons like ..there will be two button if click on dark it should dark or if u click on light it should light..or you will try animation by using jquery plugin.....

Answer (score 1):

This is the jQuery plugin you are looking for:

- http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to switch style sheets when clicking the button?
[On this page](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/) is a nice tutorial for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same and, if you can use Bootstrap, an excellent (unofficial) [Bootstrap Switch is available](http://www.larentis.eu/switch/).